# Cosmos DB, C# SQL Api - case-insensitive WHERE clause

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I am working on a project with Azure Cosmos DB using the C# SQL Api (DocumentDB) and need to know if it's possible to have a case-insensitive WHERE clause. From what I can find online it doesn't appear to be possible yet.

I want to write a query like:

```
SELECT l.CustomerName, l.LogDetail
FROM Logs l
WHERE l.CustomerName = 'Acme'
```

and have documents returned with CustomerName equal to "ACME", "Acme", or even "aCmE". I don't want to take a performance hit of a scan. I'd prefer to have the query use an index.

I know I could create a second CustomerName field with all lowercase values to filter on, but I'm looking to see if I can avoid that.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, unless it was added in the past two months, **this is not possible**.

If you use ToLower() or ToUpper() on an indexed field it will result in a scan, so that is not an option.

Some valid solutions are like you said to add another field with a case-insensitive string, or to only insert data with a certain case. It sounds like your DB is case insensitive anyway, so why not ensure that the cases really are insensitive?

Comment: Could you explain more the part of "unless it was added in the past two months". Is it possible otherwise?

Comment: @ImrePühvel it was not possible two months ago. The only way it would be possible is if they added it since then.
Like I said in my answer, its only possible with a scan

Answer (score 2):

At the time of this writing, there is now a LOWER function that can be used Cosmos SQL API queries. This would enable you to write your query like this:

```
SELECT l.CustomerName, l.LogDetail
FROM Logs l
WHERE LOWER(l.CustomerName) = 'acme'
```

[Here are the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-query-lower) for the LOWER function.

Comment: While this works, this will not use the index so will have a huge RU cost.  STRINGEQUALS(l.customerName, 'acme', true) is more efficient.

Comment: Unfortunately right now the best option is to store lowered string separately if you want to do case insensitive searches and index that field.

Answer (score 1):

There is a StringEquals function now which can be used to do case insensitive compares.

```
SELECT STRINGEQUALS("abc", "abc", false) AS c1, STRINGEQUALS("abc", "ABC", false) AS c2,  STRINGEQUALS("abc", "ABC", true) AS c3
```

returns

```
[{
    "c1": true,
    "c2": false,
    "c3": true
}]
```

Here is the documentation - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-query-stringequals